# Wii Portal disconnected in Skylanders Swap Force

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

After loading the game, the following message appear on the screen: "Portal disconnected." The portal is connected with a usb cable to the Wii. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that it is plugged in backwards, sideways or upside down. That same thing happened to me, and I just had to re adjust the cord. Once the plug is correctly plugged in, you should be fine. Hope I could help! :)